# Convert values from symbol to string in ruby

Tags: c, ruby

I'm writing a gem, and one of the pain points is my `camelize` method. I started rewriting it in C and it's working with the below implementation:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <ruby.h>

VALUE MyGem = Qnil;
VALUE Utils = Qnil;

VALUE camelize(VALUE self, VALUE str)
{
  char *orig_str = rb_string_value_cstr(&str);
  char new_str[strlen(orig_str)];

  char prev;
  int orig_idx = 0, new_idx = 0;

  new_str[0] = toupper(orig_str[0]);
  for (orig_idx = 1, new_idx = 1; orig_str[orig_idx] != '\0'; orig_idx++) {
    if (prev == '_') {
      new_str[new_idx++] = toupper(orig_str[orig_idx]);
    }
    else if (orig_str[orig_idx] != '_') {
      new_str[new_idx++] = orig_str[orig_idx];
    }
    prev = orig_str[orig_idx];
  }

  return rb_str_new(new_str, new_idx);
}

void Init_my_gem()
{
  MyGem = rb_define_module("MyGem");
  Utils = rb_define_module_under(MyGem, "Utils");
  rb_define_singleton_method(Utils, "camelize", camelize, 1);
}
```

The only problem is, the `VALUE str` can be either a symbol or a string. Does anyone know how to convert the `str` value to a string before I pull it out into a `char*`?

Comment: Perhaps `char new_str[strlen(orig_str)];` --> `char new_str[strlen(orig_str)+1];` and null character temrnated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is just to call `to_s` on `str` (`rb_string_value_cstr` will try to use `to_str`, put not `to_s`):

```
str = rb_funcall(str, rb_intern("to_s"), 0);
```

If you want this only to work for symbols, you could check for them explicitly. In this case you could call the function that implements `to_s` for symbols directly if you want (if you did this it would always use the original `Symbol#to_s` even if you open the `Symbol` class and replaced it with a different implementation):

```
if (TYPE(str) == T_SYMBOL) {
  str = rb_sym_to_s(str);
}
```

Another option is to use `rb_convert_type` with the `to_s` method, which is (as far as I can tell) pretty much equivalent to just calling `to_s`:

```
str = rb_convert_type(str, T_STRING, "String", "to_s");
```

Comment: Wow that's a great answer. Thanks so much!